# The source for breath of the mouth as the scent of an offering

Tags: sources-mekorot, commentaries, zohar

I came across this quote:

“May it be Your will that the breath that rises from my mouth at this moment be as the scent that rises from an offering in the fire of the altar..”

It seems to a quote described to Rabbi Elazar (Zohar II 20a-b).

I tried o look it up but couldn’t find it.
Could someone quote this line in Hebrew for me and help me find it’s source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Sefaria.org, it's brought in [Zohar 2:20b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Zohar.2.20b.5?vhe=New_Torat_Emet_Zohar&lang=bi&lang2=en) (on *Parashat Shemot*):

> וְהַיְינוּ דְּרִבִּי אֶלְעָזָר, כַּד הֲוָה יָתִיב בְּתַעֲנִיתָא, הֲוָה מְצַלֵּי וְאָמַר, גָּלוּי וְיָדוּעַ לְפָנְיךָ ה' אֱלהַי וִאלהֵי אֲבוֹתַי, שֶׁהִקְרַבְתִּי לְפָנֶיךָ חֶלְבִּי וְדָמִי, וְהִרְתַּחְתִּי אוֹתָם בַּחֲמִימוּת חוּלְשַׁת גּוּפִי, **יְהִי רָצוֹן מִלְּפָנֶיךָ, שֶׁיְּהֵא הָרֵיחַ הָעוֹלָה מִפִּי בְּשָׁעָה זוֹ, כְּרִיחַ הָעוֹלֶה מֵהַקָּרְבָּן בָּאֵשׁ הַמִּזְבֵּחַ, וְתִרְצֵנִי**. ‏

In translation ([as brought by Rahmiel-Hayyim Drizin](https://www.chabad.org/kabbalah/article_cdo/aid/1384851/jewish/Daily-Zohar-Shemot-Day-4.htm) on chabad.org):

> This is what Rabbi Elazar would pray and say when he fasted: It is revealed and known before You G‑d, my L-rd and the L-rd of my fathers, that I have offered up before You my fat and blood, and I have seethed them with the heat of the weakness of my body. **May it be Your will that the scent that rises from my mouth at this moment shall be as the scent that rises from an offering in the fire of the altar, and You shall favor me**.